# Return a sql value indicating whether a file exists, using c# and ExecuteCommand

Tags: sql, linq, executequery

Apologies if the question has already been answered elsewhere but I look around already with no luck. I am trying to establish whether or not a database table already exists using mvc3 and c#.

And I am putting the following sql into a resx file to call:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[%tableName%]') AND type in (N'U'))
SELECT 1
ELSE 
SELECT 0
```

This works fine in Management Studio but I am having trouble getting it to work in my c# project, where I try to call it like this:

```
public bool GetIsInstalled(string tableName)
        {
            return _db.ExecuteCommand(Scripts.CheckIfInstalled.Replace("%tableName%", tableName))==1;
        }
```

When I debug the method the value returned is actually -1, so I guess there's something wrong somewhere? I was thinking that it might be that I need to execute a query rather than a command? Could someone help me with this and please provide a code example if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExecuteCommand method returns the number of rows that were modified by the executed command. That is not what you want in this case. Instead you should be using the [ExecuteQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) method:

```
return db.ExecuteQuery<int>(
    Scripts.CheckIfInstalled.Replace("%tableName%", tableName)
).Single().Equals(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[%tableName%]') AND type in (N'U')
```

Also, check that the user specified in your connection string has access to systables.

Comment: thanks for your response but that is also returning a -1 error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which kind of db interface you are using, but if you were using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand for instance you would do something like

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

By the way: You could just use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[%tableName%]') AND type=N'U';
```

Comment: Sorry I am using Linq to SQL. I'll give your sql a try but I think its just going to return -1 again for some reason. Wondered if it was the way I was calling it from c# was what was wrong?

Comment: As kevev22 says, use `ExecuteQuery<T>` in Linq to Sql, in order to return results from a select query. `ExecuteCommand` would be used for queries that don't return results, like UPDATE or INSERT queries.